# How do I show only branch out-of-dateness information from `git status`?

Tags: git, git-status, git-track

Typically `git status` shows:

1. Current branch name (or detached HEAD status)
2. Whether upstream branch (if any) is ahead, behind or diverged
3. Changed staged for commit
4. Changes not staged for commit
5. Untracked files

How do I view only 1 and 2 without information about files? `git status`'s options typically affect display of files and trying to make it shorter typically removes branch status summary altogether.

I expect to see something like this:

```
On branch mybranch
Your branch is behind 'origin/mybranch' by 7 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
```

without anything else.

Is there some git command that shows specifically this info?

Comment: I see that `--branch` option retains this info even with `--short` or `--porcelain`, but it still spends time calculating the files diff and I don't see the `--branch-only` option.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Branch name or commit hash if detached HEAD
git symbolic-ref --quiet --short HEAD 2> /dev/null || \
    git rev-parse --short HEAD 2> /dev/null

# Check if an upstream branch is configured for the current branch
up=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref @{u} 2>/dev/null`
if [ -n "$up" -a "$up" != "@{u}" ]; then
    # Count the number of commits ahead/behind the upstream
    git rev-list --count --left-right @{u}...HEAD
fi
```

You can make a git alias or a shell script from that.

Comment: Thanks for the script. I expected `git status` to use some other command to format branch info under the hood.

Maybe it's time to contribute the `--branch-only` option for `git status`.